# (Javascript/RaphaelJS) How would I append a variable to a new object in a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, raphael

Sorry If this seems short/ un-researched (I've probably been looking in all the wrong places with the wrong logic in mind) but I feel like the answer is going to be simple/straight forward.

Say I have some variables set up, for example:

```
var path1 = paper.path("M 95, 259 L 110, 250... etc. etc.. ");

var path2 = paper.path("M 96 138 L 55, 100,... etc... etc..");
```

Insert them into a set...

```
var set1 = paper.set();
    set1.push(icon1, path1);
```

EDIT: These two steps x2 ^^^^^^^^^

Then want to go ahead and insert that new set into a new array with new objects with their own ids, So I can later reference that array when I set up a click handler function.

Basically is there any way I should/can go about attaching each set to this new array of new objects?

EDIT:

Here's more specifically what I'm working with.. I created a for loop to run through that array... which works but it only displays the first switch DIV no matter which set is clicked. Instead I want to display switch2 when set2 is clicked... or even switch3 with set3.. etc. Thanks.

```
    switches = [
        { id: 'switch1', set: set1 },
        { id: 'switch2', set: set2 }

    ],
    current,
    max,
    i;


for (i = 0, max = switches.length; i < max; i++) {
    initSwitch(switches[i].set, switches[i].id);
}

function initSwitch(switchStr, targetId) {

        txElm = document.getElementById(targetId);

     var clickHandler2 = (function (e) {
         if (current) {
             if (current === txElm) {
                 return;
             }
             current.style.display = '';
         }
         current = txElm;
         current.style.display = 'block';
         //this.toFront();
         paper.safari();
    });

    set1.click( clickHandler2 );
    set2.click( clickHandler2 );
```

FINAL EDIT:

check out this jsfiddle I just wrote up. I want the first box and image to display the "switch1" Div and the second two boxes to display the "switch2" Divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/thecomplex/AEa2X/13/

Comment: Is `segment1path` supposed to be `path1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var switches = [
        { id: 'switch1', set: set1 },
        { id: 'switch2', set: set2 }
];
var current;

for (var i = 0, max = switches.length; i < max; i++) {
    initSwitch(switches[i].set, switches[i].id);
}

function initSwitch(set, targetId) {
    var txElm = document.getElementById(targetId);

    set.click(function(e) {
        if(current == txElm)
            return;
        if(current)
             current.style.display = '';
        current = txElm;
        current.style.display = 'block';
        paper.safari();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your first example creates an object rather than an array. Your second would just add those sets to a new switches array. I need to associate each specific set with each specific switch, all within a new array. (i.e. set1 with id:switch1, set2 with id:switch2, etc.) all within this new array.

Comment: You're not making any sense. Maybe explain what you're trying to accomplish rather than how you're trying to accomplish it?

Comment: I have my code set up to display specific hidden divs (switch1, switch2) when I click on raphael objects. Your first method is what I used for awhile but for some reason it doesn't like the sets that I've set up ( I need multiple variables to display the same switch) and only worked for individual variables. Here's what I'm working with:

Comment: Why are you registering the click handler for one set on both sets? (This is your real problem.) See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey Dark Falcon, Thanks for your responses. I added a jsfiddle above with a description, trying to integrate your edit with no success, If it isn't too much of a problem check it out and let me see what you think.

Comment: It is important to pay attention to variable scope. See my updated answer. `txElm` was at the wrong scope.

Comment: Thank You for the help. As you can tell I'm still in the chopping block phase of learning javascript and the latter...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
var switches = [
    { id: 'switch1', set: set1 },
    { id: 'switch2', set: set2 }
];
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the response, Isn't quite working for me though, Check my edit above, Hopefully It clarifies more of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The `initSwitch()` function doesn't do anything with `switchStr`. It sets the click handlers for both `set1` and `set2` to the same thing, so it's no surprise they both show the same DIV.